# InvalidOperationException Incorrect Content-Type:

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, paytm

I am having a strange issue with a Payment Gateway callback request.

After every payment, the Payment Gateway is making a callback to my controller informing the status of the order.

```
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();                

            if (Request.Form.Keys.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var key in Request.Form.Keys)
                {
                    if (Request.Form[key].Contains("|"))
                    {
                        parameters.Add(key.Trim(), "");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parameters.Add(key.Trim(), Request.Form[key]);
                    }
                 }
              }
```

The above code is causing the exception [image]

Please note that out of 10 payment transactions, **the following code is working perfectly fine for 6 transactions** and only throwing an exception for 4 transactions in the production environment (We couldn't even reproduce it so far)

I've updated the code as following to avoid exception but what I didn't get it is why is it failing only for few? To know the answer, I've even logged the Request's content type for every Request as shown below

```
 _logger.Information(
                $"Request content type:{Request.ContentType}");

            if (Request.HasFormContentType && Request.Form != null && Request.Form.Keys.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var key in Request.Form.Keys)
                {
                    if (Request.Form[key].Contains("|"))
                    {
                        parameters.Add(key.Trim(), "");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parameters.Add(key.Trim(), Request.Form[key]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

To my surprise, even for failed requests, I am receiving the Content-Type as (as per my log in the above code)

**Request content type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

With this, I am sure that Payment Gateway is providing the Content-Type correctly.

**Question: What else makes `Request.HasFormContentType` reurn false?**

As avoiding exception won't solve my problem here. I must read the Request parameters. I am loosing my hair for past 2 days on this (Raised the same issue with Payment Gateway provider, they are still investigating). Any feedback much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are you accessing the request stream anywhere before asp.net core performs the model binding, i.e. any middleware or a resource filter?

Comment: No filters or middleware. I don't think we can modify the incoming Request parameters from there

Comment: If the payment provider sends a GET request instead of POST, your parameters will be in the Query rather than in Form. But you haven't shown enough information and this is just a guessing game.

Comment: This method only accepts POST requests. No payment provider will do a get request as they are the information providers not the client.